# Start MSTSC/RDP from Job only if no user is logged in remotely

Tags: powershell, rdp, mstsc

I am trying to true up out systems as we have a discrepancy from AD and our inventory management tool. I need to attempt to remote to a ton of PCs (~500). I am trying to build a GUI/script that will remote to a computer if there is no user logged in. I can do this one by one, but being as there are a ton of PCs that are in AD, but do not exist it takes a long time for each one to fail. I want to try and start a job for all of the computers in a list but only launch `mstsc` if there is no user logged in.

```
#Clear previous jobs
Get-Job | Remove-Job
$computers = $richtextbox1.Text.Split("`n") | % { $_.trim() }
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    if ($computer -ne "") {
         Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
             if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $args[0] -Count 1) {
                $uname = ""
                $uname = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Computersystem -ComputerName $args[0] |
                         Select-Object -Expand UserName
                if ($uname -like "") {
                      C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe /v:$args /h:768 /w:1024
                      # At this point the mstsc box would pop up, and the job
                      # can be killed if possible
                }
             }
         } -ArgumentList $computer
    }
}
```

If I remove `if ($uname -like "")` it will start `mstsc`. Another issue is when I do this to a block of 60 computers it will start `mstsc` for ~6 computers, wait about 45 seconds then open a couple more windows (only about 10 of the computers existed). So I think there might be an issue with jobs being running and taking too long? What would be the best way to cancel a job if it is taking too long to execute?

I'm not sure if the issue is related to `$args`/`$args[0]`. When working with jobs in the past I had to use `$args[0]`. I also know that this can produce inconsistent results with getting the logged on user with Windows 10, so if there is a better option there, that would be helpful.

Comment: I'd use a named parameter inside the scriptblock (`Param($comp)`) and put the arguments for `mstsc.exe` in quotes (`mstsc.exe "/v:$comp" "/h:768" "/w:1024"`).

Comment: Thanks! I did both of these things, at least the $args part isn't a question anymore with the named param. Now it is just the no user logged in part. Whenever I add that part in, it doesn't run mstsc no matter what.

Comment: Try `-not $uname` instead of `$uname -like ""`. The WMI request should an empty value to the variable when no username was found.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this check to see if a user was logged in, and it worked.

```
$NOTNULLIFLOCKED = $null
$NOTNULLIFLOCKED = gwmi -Class win32_process -computername $comp -Filter "Name='LogonUI.exe'"
if ($NOTNULLIFLOCKED -ne $null)
{
    # No Active Session (LogonUI.exe Running)
    # If LogonUI.exe is running, that means the login box is currently present on the screen.
    & C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe "/v:$comp" "/h:768" "/w:1024"
}
```

I am running into another issue now, but I will post another question.